# Cannot open XML file (Parsin error/Permissions error)

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I've built an app for Android and signed it for Play Store publishment.

I then downloaded my app `apk` file so I could edit the Android Manifest (`AndroidManifest.xml` file) but I get a permissios error so I can't open it.

I assume it's because i have signed it with a developer key.

I was able to extract the XML file so I could try to edit it, but now I get parsing error messages and permission error messages; I get different error messages with different software.

How can I edit this file in Linux or Windows? Is there software that will ignore the fact that it comes from a signed app? What software should I use to decompile the app with developer password permissions? I built the app in Intel XDK.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to publish the app again to Google Play if you sign it with another certificate. It has to be identical.

"Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key." - From the Android Developer site.

Comment: So how do I edit the AndroidManifest file and compile the apk file again so that I can upload it to the playstore?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can decompile the apk and modify the manifest and re-package it to a runnable apk later. Of course, that's the case when you only want to modify the apk and run on your devices. Otherwise, you cannot update the app on the store because you have to sign the apk with the same key as you did with the original one.

There is an app named "Apk Editor" on the Play Store that let you modify the manifest file that but it doesn't work for every case. Let me know if it does or doesn't work for you.

Edit : I just read that you want to publish/update the app on the Play Store, why don't you just edit the manifest in the project and sign it the key you used for the first one ?

Comment: APK Editor app freezes when I try to use it on the Android x32 4.4 Operating System.